# What Runes should I prioritize buying?

Tags: league-of-legends

I primarily play Ranged AD, various Junglers, or solo top champions. Looking for which runes are the most universally useful/most cost effective to buy across many roles. These are the sets of runes I own.

Marks:

- Flat AD
- Armor Pen
- Magic Pen
- Attack Speed

Seals:

- Flat Armor
- Mana Regen/Level

Glyphs:

- Flat Magic Resist
- Flat Cooldown Reduction

Quints:

- Flat HP
- Flat AD
- Movement Speed

Comment: If you are in the jungle i would get some Quints-Life-steal runes. They help a lot especially when using the hunters machete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost I'd get some scaling magic resist glyphs. The flat ones are great when you're mid, or you know you're going against a mage up top (e.g. vlad) but for blind pick or bottom lane or jungle I'd always go with scaling over flat.

Other than that, you have just about any runes you'd want to cover those roles.

I'd recommend picking up a mage page (flat AP quints, flat AP yellows, magic pen reds) and a support page (avarice quints and yellows, flat armor reds); being able to play a variety of roles is more important than being specialized at one IMO.

Answer (score 4):

I found this image flow chart to be rather useful for getting up and running with runes. These are general idea runes and once you get to know some champs you may want to get something different but I feel like this is a good start.

[image: LoLRunes]

Comment: For the most part I have the runes that this guide shows, XD
I own around 25 champions or so (most AD, but I have at least two or three for each role) and have around 270 wins under my belt. This guide seems like it's for people that have just hit 20/30. So I guess I'm looking for the next step after this.

Comment: Ah okay. Well I guess the next step would be getting something more champ specific? I know I have some runes specifically for some champs.

Answer (score 1):

The Runes you have are a solid baseline and should work ok for most situations and champions.

Other Runes you might want to think about:

Seals:

- Scaling Armor
  When you are in the top lane against an AP opponent like Vlad you don't need the armor early on so scaling armor runes perform better in the mid- to lategame.
- Scaling HP
  Mostly for the Mundo Jungler but there are some other champions that can make good use of them, too.

Glyphs:

- Scaling Magic Resist
  Against AD based top champions you don't need magic resistance early on and the scaling runes will outperform the flat runes around the time you start fighting in other lanes.

Quints:

- Attack Speed
  For some champions like Irelia you might want to use AS Quints + ArPen Marks.
- Flat AP
  Maokai Jungler uses Flat AP Quints with AS Marks and you can use them later when you try AP Carry.